# PHP math does not work in sql value ZERO

Tags: php, mysql, math, phpmyadmin

I am trying to math between value of 0 but in php code it's work properly but when that value come from database then it does not work.

Here is a demo to test only PHP code:

```
<?php
$a = 0;
echo $a+1;
?>
```

The result of this code

> 1

That ran properly, but when it came from database table then the "+" math does not work properly.

Here is my full code:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
require('config2.php');

// move_up & move_down ** up_down //

$move_up = $_POST['move_up'];

$move_down = $_POST['move_down'];

$up_down1 = $_POST['up_down'];

$up_down11 = $_POST['up_down'];

$forid = $_POST['forid'];

$up = $up_down1-1;

$down = $up_down11+1;

if($move_up) {
    if($up_down1) {
        $insert=mysql_query("UPDATE widgets_mata SET `up_down` = '$up' WHERE `widgets_mata_id` = $forid");
        header("Location: yyy.php");
    }
}

if($move_down) {
    if($up_down11) {
        $insert2=mysql_query("UPDATE widgets_mata SET `up_down` = '$down' WHERE `widgets_mata_id` = $forid");
        header("Location: yyy.php");
    }
}   
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php $query2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM widgets_mata ORDER BY up_down ASC");
while($rows2=mysql_fetch_assoc($query2))
{ 
    $widgets_mata_id2=$rows2['widgets_mata_id'];
    $widgets_id2=$rows2['widgets_id'];
    $up_down2=$rows2['up_down'];
    $field2=$rows2['field'];

    if($field2=='R') {
        $query3 = "SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE `widgets_id`=$widgets_id2";
        $result3 = mysql_query($query3);

        while($rows3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3))
        {
            $widgets_id3=$rows3['widgets_id'];
            $fu_name3=$rows3['fu_name'];
            $func_name3=$rows3['func_name'];
            $func3=$rows3['func'];
?>
  <h3> <?php echo $fu_name3; ?></h3>
  <div>
   Plaese select your options 
   <br />
   <br />
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <label>
  <input name="forid" type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="<?php echo $widgets_mata_id2; ?>" />
  <input name="up_down" type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="<?php echo $up_down2; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="move_up" value="Move Up" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="move_down" value="Move Down" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Save" />
  </label>
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
  <label>
    <input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="Delete" />
  </label>
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
  <label>
    <input type="submit" name="button3" id="button3" value="Cancel" />
  </label>
</form>


  </div>
<?php 
        }
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my *config2.php*

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','')
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("myweb");
?>
```

Here is my SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `widgets_mata` (
  `widgets_mata_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `widgets_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `up_down` int(10) DEFAULT '1',
  `field` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `widgets_mata`
--

INSERT INTO `widgets_mata` (`widgets_mata_id`, `widgets_id`, `up_down`, `field`) VALUES
(1, 1, 0, 'R'),
(2, 2, 2, 'R'),
(3, 3, 3, 'R');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `widgets_mata`
--
ALTER TABLE `widgets_mata`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`widgets_mata_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `widgets_mata`
--
ALTER TABLE `widgets_mata`
  MODIFY `widgets_mata_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

My problem is with the "0" here:

[image]

Then the addition is not working. But when the value is "1"or"2"or"3" then the code works properly.

If you don't understand my question so please run my codes I give full code here

Comment: This normally happens when you have not initialized the value to an integer. You also are not testing that the $_POST values actually exist before using their values, this could well be the cause of your problems. You also do not appear to be doing any sanity checking of $_POST values, also dangerous

Comment: `mysql_query` is depreciated, please check out `mysqli.query`

Comment: `mysql_query` returns `TRUE` if successful and `FALSE` if not, what value are $insert and $insert2 when completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I having run you code and I just found you solution.
in your Phpmyadmin database in side mate table cell name `up_down` update that, please goto  **Structure>`up_down` click Change>Attributes{UNSIGNED ZEROFILL} select that>Save** And then you can test that you will find the different.
[image]